# Display custom library in webpart?

Tags: web-part

I created a library called **Training** and I want to display that on my page in a web part.  How is this achieved?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit the page, click add web part and pick the "Training" library from the menu.  You can then edit the web part properties and customize the view shown in the web part to whatever makes sense.

Comment: My Training library doesn't show, so do I add the Shared Documents library and then configure that?

Comment: The Add Web Part dialog can be confusing, Are you sure you dont just have to scroll to the right in the dialog (a little arrow at the bottom of the lists)  Also, is your library in the same site as the page where you want it to appear?

Comment: this is what i see

Comment: You may have to edit the page in Designer and add the view that way - http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/customize-data-views-and-forms-using-sharepoint-designer-HA101631678.aspx

Comment: Use Site Actions -> View All Site Content to confirm your Training library is on this same site.